# Calling OnClick Twice - Once in Tag and Once in Externally Hosted Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a link that is tied to an externally hosted JS script that I cannot change.  The external script uses jquery to bind to the click function to perform an action.

```
<script...src="external cannot change"></script>
<a class="clicker" href="link">Click me</a>
```

I need to perform another action onClick as well.  But when I do the below, the browser only runs the onclick even bound in the external script.

```
<a class="clicker" href="link" onclick="doThis();">Click me</a>
```

It does not run doThis().  It only performs the action specified in the externally hosted script.

Is there a method to run 2 onClick events - 1 stored in the external script and 1 coded locally?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a click event with jQuery. You can add as many of these as you want.

```
$(".clicker").click(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but it still didn't work.  I think the issue is that the externally hosted script opens a new tab, and I want the on-page script to redirect the current tab to a new URL.  Should a simple window.location work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different event. onmouseup should work well. If you want to catch the event and prevent the other script from doing the onclick, use onmousedown and then add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery event binding instead of attribute based events.

```
function MyOwnClick(e){
  // do something.
}

$(".clicker").bind("click", MyOwnClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the doThis() function for onclick.You can add another jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clicker").click(function(){
    //whatever you want to do
    });
});
```